# Thymeleaf JS cannot pass parameters

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I want to use thymeleaf call method to query a class and return data; but JS can't pass in parameters. I don't know how to do it, please help me.

js code

```
<script th:inline="javascript">   
 ... 
function (value, row, index) {
    var temp =[[${@member.getName(value)}]];
    return temp ;
}
...
</script>
```

java code

```
package com.ruoyi.framework.web.service;

import com.ruoyi.app.domain.Member;
import com.ruoyi.app.service.IMemberService;
import com.ruoyi.common.utils.StringUtils;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

/**
 * @author Hamming_Yu on 2018/12/14.
 */
@Service("member")
public class MemberService {
    @Autowired
    private IMemberService memberService;

    public String getName(String id){
        if(StringUtils.isNotEmpty(id)){
            Member member = memberService.selectMemberById(id);
            if(StringUtils.isNotNull(member)){
                return member.getUserName();
            }
        }
        return "";
    }

}
```

Java gets parameters: null

I found that only when thymeleafis loaded can JS be executed. All parameters are empty. Is there any way to make thymeleaf lazy to load?

Comment: Do you want to use thymeleaf variable in javascript??

Comment: No, I want to use thymeleaf to query backend data, just like JSTL can directly call the background method